# Failed to create cache dir :Vert.x : Jenkins Build

Tags: java, jenkins, vert.x

My Unit Test project is running into an error when configured with Jenkins. The Tests run fine when I run the maven test locally from Command prompt.

Error I get :

```
feature ("Verify GET User Details API")
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create cache dir
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:78)
    at com.ibm.wce.scbn.cc.runner.BaseRunner.feature(BaseRunner.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create cache dir
    at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileResolver.setupCacheDir(FileResolver.java:332)
    at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileResolver.<init>(FileResolver.java:87)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:165)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.vertx(VertxImpl.java:92)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:32)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:27)
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:75)
    at com.ibm.wce.scbn.cc.util.TokenUtil.<init>(TokenUtil.java:32)
    at com.ibm.wce.scbn.cc.util.TokenUtil.getInstance(TokenUtil.java:46)
    at com.ibm.wce.scbn.cc.stepdefinitions.AccountsByID.we_send_Get_request_to_service_for_Account_with_source_and_iui(AccountsByID.java:369)
    at ✽.We send Get request to service for Account "1" with source "1" and iui "1"(./features/AccountsByID/AccountsByID.feature:7)
```

TokenUtil.java

```
public class TokenUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TokenUtil.class.getName());
    private static TokenUtil TOKEN_INSTANCE = null;
    private static Vertx VERTX = null;
    private static JWTAuthOptions JWTAUTHOPS = new JWTAuthOptions();

    private TokenUtil() throws Exception {

        try {
            VERTX = Vertx.vertx();
            JsonObject objJason = new JsonObject(VERTX.fileSystem().readFileBlocking(System.getProperty("privatejwtpath")));
            JWTAUTHOPS.addJwk(objJason);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to load private JWK json file", e);
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public static TokenUtil getInstance() throws Exception {

        if (TOKEN_INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (TokenUtil.class) {
                TOKEN_INSTANCE = new TokenUtil();
            }
        }
        return TOKEN_INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getJWT(String iui) {

        JWTOptions jwtOptions = new JWTOptions();
        JsonObject payLoad = new JsonObject();
        jwtOptions.setAlgorithm("RS256");
        jwtOptions.setExpiresInSeconds(300);
        JWTAuth jwt = JWTAuth.create(VERTX, JWTAUTHOPS);
        payLoad.put("ibm", new JsonObject().put("iui", iui));
        return jwt.generateToken(payLoad, jwtOptions);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: My guess is you are lacking permissions to create folder. You can check this https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_configuring_vert_x_cache and specify custom location of cache folder or disable it in total.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by disabling Cache